# «Так же» — слитно или раздельно в данном предложении?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

*Аня легко влюбляется и **также / так же** легко разочаровывается в мужчинах.*

Comment: Если *же* можно убрать или переставить, тогда раздельно. Слитно могло бы писаться: Аня - легко влюбляется и также разочаровывается в мужчинах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написание раздельное: *Аня легко влюбляется и **так же** легко разочаровывается в мужчинах.*

Сочетание ***ТАК ЖЕ*** относится к наречию "легко" (в такой же степени легко).

Сравнить: *Аня влюбляется и разочаровывается в мужчинах **одинаково легко.***

Comment: Интересно, что "тоже" тоже подходит.

Comment: Серж, а какой у вас ответ, вы не хотели бы его записать и объяснить?

Comment: Вот так всегда...

Comment: Представьте, что это контрольная работа в школе. Нужно выполнить задание и сдать учителю. Все прилежно думают над СВОИМ ответом, но мне хочется свериться с кем-нибудь. И только один ученик ничего сам не решает.  И вот так всегда...

Comment: Нет, один учитель проверяет непутёвого ученика... Как-то так получается...

Comment: Это тот, кто честно пишет контрольную?

Comment: Нет, это тот, кто любит новаторство и ненавидит логику.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Спасибо за правку.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае корректно слитное написание. Здесь также союз. В данном случае можно подобрать другие союзы.

Анна тоже влюбляется.
И Анна влюбляется.

При раздельном написание у нас наречие с частицей же, которую можно опустить. К тому же, как отмечается в справочнике Д.Э. Розенталя, за сочетанием так же часто следует наречие как.

Ср.: Он так же, как и ты, хотел уехать.

Опустим частицу «же»:

Он так, как и ты, хотел уехать.

Также, я бы хотела поблагодарить организаторов мероприятия.

Comment: Анна так же легко влюбляется, как и разочаровывается. ТАК - это наречие степени. Можно сравнить с СПП: Анна так легко влюбляется,  как не умеет никто. Анна так легко влюбляется, что просто удивляешься. Это СПП  придаточными степени, Указательное слово ТАК относится к наречию.  В приведенном предложении ТАК относится тоже к наречию, а не к глаголу.